# CSS: How to get this effect ? (Picture on top of a card, going outside it)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm fairly new to CSS, so I apologize if someone asked for this effect before, I don't know the name of it.

I need to create this (picture 1), I currently have this (picture 2):
[image]
I don't know hot to create this effect or what is the name of it.
I have tried playing with z-index and padding, but I don't think that this is the best solution.

Here is the code (for the picture 2):

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="picture.png" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Mirion Jones</h4>
                <p class="card-position">CEO Founder</p>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Bootstrap 4.

Comment: negative margin top or negative position absolute. Take your pick.

Comment: It may help to show what you have tried and what goes specifically wrong.

Comment: position absolute is your friend. (the box has to be position relative) after that you can just use top, left, right and bottom to move it around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope the code below helps. I set the image size to 60px by 60px, and set the `margin` and `top` accordingly, you should change them with your desired dimension.

```css
.card-img-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 60px !important;
  height: 60px;
}

.card {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top img-circle rounded-circle" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Mirion Jones</h4>
        <p class="card-position">CEO Founder</p>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @IkePr no problem. Happy coding.